# RegExp - Using the dollar sign to differentiate hex from decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a RegExp in JavaScript to parse a number in either hex or decimal.

For example the following would be valid `RST 10h` or `RST 16`.

This works:

```
/rst ((\b10h\b)|(\b16\b))/.exec("rst 10h")
```

I would prefer to use `$` as a prefix to denote hex numbers but this does not work

```
/rst ((\b\$10\b)|(\b16\b))/.exec("rst $10")
```

even with escaping the dollar?

Comment: You don't need the `\b` word boundary pattern, since you have a space before it.

Comment: 1) `rst ((\b10h\b)|(\b16\b))` = `rst (10h|16)\b`. 2) `/rst ((\b\$10\b)|(\b16\b))/` can be `/rst (\$10|16)\b/`